# FiraSans and XCharter -- XeLaTeX

Tags: fonts, xetex

I found both packages and wanted to use Fira Sans as sans serif font and XCharter as serif, body text font.

But for some reason, only compiling with `pdflatex` works with both fonts at the same time. Both packages work with `xelatex` when either one is without the other. It seems that when I compile a document with both packages using `xelatex`, only the *last one* is active. Of course it would be easier to use the downloaded .otf's with xelatex, but I'm curious why one package replaces the other, since one is for a sans serif font, the other, a serif font.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[osf]{XCharter}
\usepackage{FiraSans}
\usepackage{inconsolata}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\title{Um título qualquer}
\author{Fulano de Tal}
\date{}
\maketitle

\section{Seção de teste}
\lipsum[1-2]

\section{Lorem ipsum}
\lipsum[3-4]

\end{document}
```

Comment: The XCharter package is not compatible with `fontspec` and the font is not available in (Open|True)Type format.

Comment: @egreg Yes, XCharter is also available as OpenType, I *do* have them (the .otfs). By the way, the question is correct: they kill each other's font settings, but loaded alone seem to work.

Comment: @Manuel The `XCharter` package only supports Type1 fonts: it starts off with `\RequirePackage[LY1,T1]{fontenc}` and has no option for `fontspec`.

Comment: @egreg You are right, I understood that it wasn't available in OpenType format.

Answer (score 4):

Currently the `XCharter` package has no support for the OpenType version that is however available in TeX Live.

The workaround is simple: use `\setmainfont` directly.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{XCharter}[Numbers=OldStyle]

\usepackage{FiraSans}
\usepackage{inconsolata}


\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\title{Um título qualquer}
\author{Fulano de Tal}
\date{}
\maketitle

\section{Seção de teste}
Digits in Charter: 1234567890. \lipsum[1-2]

\section{Lorem ipsum}
\lipsum[3-4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This works with `xelatex`or `lualatex`:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{FiraSans}
\usepackage{inconsolata}
\setmainfont{XCharter-Roman}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\title{Um título qualquer}
\author{Fulano de Tal}
\date{}
\maketitle

\section{Seção de teste}
\lipsum[1-2]

\section{Lorem ipsum}
\lipsum[3-4]

\end{document}
```

The Package `XCharter` doesn't test the engine it always uses the `pdflatex` route.